# Имитация комбинации “Shift + Left Click"

Tags: javascript, userjs

Использую user.js. Нужно эмулировать сочетание Shift + Left Click на элементе с id. Пробовал `window.open`, но не подходит, т.к ссылки генерируются автоматически.

```
        function openClient() {
            window.open("динамические ссылки", "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=50, left=50, width=450, height=615");
        }
```

Отлично работает:

```
var start = document.getElementById("startBtn").click();
```

Можно ли как-то изменить, чтобы клик происходил с зажатой клавишей shift сразу при заходе на страницу, но без jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно создать объект события [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) вручную, передав ему в конструктор кроме базовых параметров ещё и `shiftKey: true`:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var event = new MouseEvent("click", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window,
    shiftKey: true
  });
  document.getElementById("link").dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<a id="link" href="https://google.ru">Link</a>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Click" />
```

Для наглядности примера событие генерируется по клику на кнопку. Но при загрузке страницы, если заменить `document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click"` на `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"`, оно тоже работает.

Проверено на работоспособность в Opera 49.0.2725.47

---

В IE 11.125.16299.0 `new MouseEvent` работать отказывается, но зато там работает deprecated метод [initMouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent). Однако передачу `true` в качестве параметра `shiftKey` он благополучно игнорирует, открывая ссылку в том же окне:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
  event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, true, false, 0, null);
  document.getElementById("link").dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<a id="link" href="https://google.ru">Link</a>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Click" />
```

---

А чтобы было не слишком скучно, поведение в Firefox 57.0.2 отличается и от Opera, и от IE: в нём работают как `new MouseEvent`, так и `initMouseEvent`, однако при передаче `true` в `shiftKey` в обоих случаях вообще ничего не происходит (без `shiftKey` работает).

Comment: Работает, однако если вставить код в Tampermonkey или просто в консоль, то ничего не происходит, хром будто игнорируют, это можно обойти? Или просто зажать shift программно, а остальное выполнялось будто кнопка нажаат физически

Comment: @АлександрСоболев про Tampermonkey впервые слышу, так что ничего на этот счет сказать не могу. А что конкретно вы писали в консоли? Я, на примере данной страницы, вбил в Opera в консоль `document.querySelector("a[href='/posts/762563/revisions']").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window, shiftKey: true }))`, и это сработало. Через простой JS на странице можно только эмулировать нажатие клавиш, из соображений безопасности. Причем даже эмуляция того же shift-а не везде работает. Программно - только если в плагинах такая возможность есть, и то не факт